# When is CMFCListCtrl::OnGetCellBkColor function called?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using CMFCListCtrl to control background color of each cell when i want in my MFC Project..

so I'm overriding OnGetCellBkColor() to define each cell's background color.. but the problem is this funcion is never called during runtime.

even when I add the items. when is this function called? Can i call this function manually when I want?

Comment: Could you please add the code you got so far? We call it a [mcve] and it would be helpful to answer your question. Answers without code examples normally get downvotes because they are too broad or not comprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnGetCellBkColor` is called from within OnCustomDraw. So it is called in a normal sequence when items are drawn. But it is never called when you defined you list control as owner drawn. So `LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` must not be set to the styles.

You have the source code to find this information by yourself.

Also a problem might be that you didn't subclassed the created control or never created the control as a `CMFCListCtrl`.